# bash zcat head causes pipefail?

Tags: bash

```
set -eu 
VAR=$(zcat file.gz  |  head -n 12)
```

works fine

```
set -eu   -o pipefail
VAR=$(zcat file.gz  |  head -n 12)
```

causes bash to exit with failure.
How is this causing a pipefail?

Note that file.gz contains millions of lines (~ 750 MB, compressed).

Comment: As an aside, `set -e` and `set -u` are both... to put it kindly... *controversial*, with a multitude of subtle corner cases (and per-version behavior inconsistencies where attempts were made to modify non-POSIX-specified details in their behavior between releases). Unless you understand all the scenarios described in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112), and don't need compatibility with bash releases you can't test against, you might reconsider their use. Static checking with http://shellcheck.net/ has fewer caveats.

Comment: (By contrast, `pipefail` is generally a Good Idea; when you have a specific case where you want to allow a pipeline component to fail, you can allow that explicitly; for this case, `var=$( { zcat file.gz ||:; } | head -n 12)` will do).

Comment: ...aside: lower-case `var` is correct; see [the POSIX environment variable spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html)'s naming convention: All-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the shell or system; lowercase names are reserved for application use. That applies to non-exported shell variables as well since setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The chain of events causing the error is as follows:

1. You're telling the shell that your entire pipeline should be considered to have failed if any component failed.
2. You're telling `zcat` to write its output to `head`.
3. Then you're telling `head` to exit after reading 12 lines, out of a much-longer-than-12-line input stream.

In short: `zcat` has its destination pipeline closed early, and wasn't able to successfully write a decompressed version of your input file! It doesn't have any way of knowing that this was due to user intent, via something erroneous happening.

If you were using `zcat` to write to a disk and it ran out of space, or to a network stream and there was a connection loss, it would be entirely correct and appropriate for it to exit with a status indicating a failure. This is simply another case of that rule.

---

The specific error which `zcat` is being given by the operating system is `EPIPE`, returned by the `write` syscall under the following condition: *An attempt is made to write to a pipe that is not open for reading by any process.*

After `head` (the only reader of this FIFO) has exited, for any write to the input side of pipeline *not* to return EPIPE would be a bug. For `zcat` to silently ignore an error writing its output, and thus be able to generate an inaccurate output stream without an exit status reflecting this event, would *likewise* be a bug.

---

If you don't want to change any of your shell options, by the way, one workaround you might consider is using process substitution:

```
var=$(head -n 12 < <(zcat file.gz))
```

In this case, `zcat` is not a pipeline component, and its exit status is not considered for purposes of determining success. (You might test whether `$var` is 12 lines long, if you want to come up with an independent success/fail determination).

---

A more comprehensive solution could be implemented by pulling in a Python interpreter, with its native gzip support. A native Python implementation (compatible with both Python 2 and 3.x), embedded in a shell script, might look something like:

```bash
zhead_py=$(cat <<'EOF'
import sys, gzip
gzf = gzip.GzipFile(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
outFile = sys.stdout.buffer if hasattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer') else sys.stdout
numLines = 0
maxLines = int(sys.argv[2])
for line in gzf:
    if numLines >= maxLines:
        sys.exit(0)
    outFile.write(line)
    numLines += 1
EOF
)
zhead() { python -c "$zhead_py" "$@"; }
```

...which gets you a `zhead` that doesn't fail if it runs out of input data, but *does* pass through a failed exit status for genuine I/O failures or other unexpected events. (Usage is of the form `zhead in.gz 5`, to read 5 lines from `in.gz`).

Comment: Outstanding answer!  Thank you for the details.  While these things may be obvious to a trained computer programmer or very experienced coder, there are many, many people who write scripts & code that are not computer scientists-by-training, and many of us are self-taught.  The reality is that many of us amateurs don't have time or even the knowledge of *how* to dig into the inner workings of bash, pipes, streams, syscalls, etc.   When you don't understand the fine details of streams, `write`, etc., it is conceivable by pure imagination) that `head` properly terminates a filestream.

Comment: Nice explanation and understandable... now are there any programs that *can* head from a gzip file without error? Something perhals called zhead?

Comment: @Freek, ...you could write something easily enough in any language (like Python) with a native gzip library; that way it's all in one process, so you don't have the problem with gzip not having any way of knowing that the inability to write to head is intentional.

Comment: @Freek, ...of course, I could also just see a `zhead` script using the `gunzip > >(head "$@")` workaround given here and ignoring `head`'s exit status, on the theory that `head` is unlikely to fail if `gzip` does the right thing. Not entirely solid -- doesn't account for command-line usage failures -- but it handles *most* of the case.

Comment: This explanation is very helpful! It seems though, there could be a different type of error inside of `<(zcat file.gz)` (i.e. anything other than the pipe terminating because head exits) that would not be caught if `head` can succeed without failing.

Comment: @steveb, quite right; it takes extra work in bash to retrieve the exit status from a process substitution (you need to `wait` for its PID, in a version of bash new enough to have process substitutions set `$!` at all).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It would be great to have an option in `zcat` to specify the number of output lines. I commented on this because I had two separate scripts that had a bunch of pipes, where `zcat | head` was part of both scripts, but one would consistently fail and one would consistently pass (neither seemed intermittent). This was painful to track down but it appears to be a race condition. I am surprised it doesn't fail more often than it does, but I don't have deep insight into the underlying implementations. In short, one has to expect `zcat | head` to fail some of the time.

Comment: Given how popular this answer is, I almost wonder if I should write a second one (or an extension) that implements a `zhead` tool in Python or another language that can actually do the error-management correctly, and shows how to embed it in a shell script. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That might be a good idea, as I am not fond of a solution that could mask other errors.

Comment: Why is it `< <(zcat file.gz)` rather than just `<(zcat file.gz)`?

Comment: @erwaman, `<(...)` expands to a filename (of a named pipe or equivalent thereto) which can be read to get the output of `...`. In `< <(...)`, the `<` up front redirects from that filename.

Comment: @beroe, that was definitely an improvement in tone, and I appreciate it. On the other hand, I'm not sure the opening list did in fact list _reasons_. Do you think the current edit strikes an appropriate balance?

Comment: Yes @CharlesDuffy your current edit is a nice solution. Thanks for being open to the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use

```
zcat file.gz  | awk '(NR<=12)'
```

The price is that you need to go through all the `zcat`, no early stop based on the lines you specified.