# Curious case of failed pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, ldd

Can anyone provide me with any insight into possible causes for the following issue. Most of the time I can run `( set -o pipefail; ldd --version | head -n 1; echo $? )` and get the following.

```
$ ( set -o pipefail; ldd --version | head -n 1; echo $? ) 
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9) 2.23
0
```

But then randomly it will start to fail

```
$ ( set -o pipefail; ldd --version | head -n 1; echo $? ) 
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9) 2.23
141
```

For what its worth I've seen this on Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 and also on RHEL 7.3 ppc64le machine

Comment: I'm *certain* this is a duplicate of something already in the knowledgebase; just need to find it...

Comment: Ahh, [bash zcat head causes pipefail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516177/bash-zcat-head-causes-pipefail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`141` is `EINIT`. i.e. the process was interrupted.

What's happening is that `head -1` closes its input stream after reading the first line. When `ldd` tries to write to the closed pipe, it fails with `EINIT`.

Normally you don't see this - programs exit with an error after `head` has taken what it wants, but you don't see the error outcome. But because you've `set -o pipefail`, you see the error.

This is intermittent because there is a buffer in the pipe, and the scheduling is unpredictable. Sometimes `ldd` has finished writing before `head` closes the pipe.

You can consistently see the failure if you do `ldd | echo` (because echo immediately closes stdin), and you can consistently see it succeed with `ldd | cat` (because `cat` always consumes until EOF).