# Bash script to exit when any command (including non-simple commands) fail

Tags: bash

I have a script

```
#! /bin/sh
set -eux

command_a

command_b | command_c

while [ true ]; do
    command_d
done
```

I'd like this to fail when any command fails. If `command_a` fails, the script fails, but if `command_b` or `command_d` (not sure about `command_c`) fail, the script carries on.

Comment: Add a `pipefail` option to that also, `set -euxo pipefail`

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Comment: I'd **strongly** suggest saying `while true; do` instead of `while [ true ]; do` -- the latter implies that `while [ false ]; do` would behave differently, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should not happen if you are using `set -eux`, may be I can tell better if I knew the actual command.
One way to achieve exiting can be to use `||`

```
while [ true ]; do
    command_d || exit 1
done
```

`a || b` means "do a (completely). If it didn't succeed, do b"

Also, you should use `set -euxo pipefail`

Refer this: https://vaneyckt.io/posts/safer_bash_scripts_with_set_euxo_pipefail/

Comment: I **strongly** disagree with the characterization of `set -e` as "safe". See the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) (below the allegory), and the list of incompatibilities between different shells' implementations of `set -e` at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/. Because bash has no way to distinguish between a command correctly returning an exit status that indicates a false result of a test and an exit status indicating an error, `set -e`'s behavior is necessarily full of heuristics that try to guess among the cases.

Comment: ...among these heuristics is maintaining the "checked" flag to determine whether an operation is considered part of a test or conditional -- its behavior, particular in the context of function calls or compound commands, is almost universally misunderstood.

Comment: (`set -u` is not nearly as bad as `set -e`, but similarly, it [tends to break otherwise correct code not explicitly written for compatibility](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112); consequently, `pipefail` is the only part of this advice that isn't controversial at all... though even then, [its use occasionally leads to surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516177/bash-zcat-head-causes-pipefail)).