# what difference -v verbose in curl makes?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, curl

I made this utility (part of utility code)

```
#!/bin/bash
url_prefix='https://www.javatpoint.com/'
url_suffix='java-tutorial'

  curl -v $url_prefix$url_suffix | grep -m 1 '>next' | cut -d '"' -f 4 >temp.html
```

If I remove -v from curl commnad;it starts saying failed to write body. I am not able to understand why this happens.
full code is available at https://github.com/RishiPrakash/JavatpointAsPdf

Comment: Can you show the actual error?

Comment: BTW, if you're trying to parse HTML this way -- it's a really exceedingly fragile approach. Using a *real* HTML parser, XPath engine, etc. will yield far fewer surprises.

Comment: Why downvotes? :)

Answer (score 2):

#### `curl -v` does not cause or suppress your error, but the error can get lost in the other log messages `-v` writes.

`curl -v` *only* determines whether verbose logging is written to stderr; it does not impact your pipeline in any other way.

---

#### The error is actually caused by `curl | grep -m 1`.

To explain the error, then:

`grep -m 1` tells `grep` to quit after the first match.

This means that all subsequent writes by curl into the FIFO read by grep will cause an `EPIPE` error, as the program on the other end of the pipeline is no longer reading. Consequently, `curl` cannot write the rest of the body, so you get the error in question.

*However*, since the rest of your pipeline doesn't actually use any of that body content, this is expected and harmless.

---

If you want to suppress this error, letting `curl` write the whole output even if `grep` doesn't need it, you can do that easily enough:

```
content=$(curl -v "$url_prefix$url_suffix")
printf '%s\n' "$content" | grep -m 1 '>next' | ...
```

The command substitution reads the *entire* output of `curl`, so the error doesn't take place.

Comment: The OP is asking why (s)he only gets this error when (s)he removes the `-v`; but your answer seems like it would apply equally with or without the `-v`?

Comment: @ruakh, keep in mind that all the extra output from `curl -v` goes only to stderr. Thus, it doesn't interact with the pipeline at all, so the only reasonable distinction between the two is just *whether the error is displayed to the user*, not whether it happens.

Comment: @ruakh, ...you can repro this one easily yourself -- compare `curl -v https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial | tee /dev/null | head -n 1` with and without the `tee`.

Comment: I'm not saying this answer is wrong, I'm saying that it doesn't quite answer the OP's question. Maybe the problem is that the question is ill-posed -- the OP thinks that removing the `-v` causes the error, but actually [something else] -- but in that case I think you should at least indicate that in the answer.

Comment: (By the way, I can't fully reproduce your claim that the `tee` removes the error. On my system, `... | tee /dev/null | head -n 1` still sends a SIGPIPE to `...` pretty quickly after the first line, albeit not quite as quickly as bare `... | head -n 1`.)

Comment: @ruakh, hmm -- I'm going to have to go back and reread the POSIX spec for `tee`. My impression was that it was obligated to keep reading until no more writers were left.

Comment: @ruakh, ...ahh, changed in a newer version of the spec, such that implementations are no longer permitted to ignore write errors. *sigh*.

Comment: @ruakh, ...edited to be explicit about what's going on. Is that better?

Comment: I think so, yes; but I'm not clear on *how* `-v` could prevent the error from being displayed?

Comment: @ruakh, heh -- just reread the original question. Presumably the error is just lost in the logs. It's certainly displayed even with `-v` present, even for me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So this way content=$(curl -v "$url_prefix$url_suffix")
printf '%s\n' "$content" | grep -m 1 '>next' | ... , even if I don't use -v; things should go fine?

Comment: @Rishi, `-v` doesn't change behavior of that command either way -- the verbose logs go to stderr, so they aren't captured in `content`, aren't fed to grep, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay Charles, I think I need to ponder on this for a good amount of time to understand the behaviour. Thanks for all the help :) Namaste (greetings) from India.

Comment: If it helps understanding -- one thing to keep in mind that all parts of a pipeline run at the same time; instead of running the first part and then the second, they're both run simultaneously, with the stdout of the first program connected to the stdin of the second -- that's why when the second program exits before the first one has finished writing all its output, the first one gets an error during the write operation, which is what is reported here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516177/bash-zcat-head-causes-pipefail for a related case, but with different programs on each side.

Answer (score 0):

As per man page of curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html , by using verbose, you can see more debugging information about curl operation
It's failing in your case, because you are doing further operation on that 'more information', which not present if you are note using verbose mode(-v)

Comment: "Doing further operations on that 'more information'" is only true if that additional information is written to stdout. The POSIX standard specifies that stderr should be used for "diagnostic content", and output added by `-v` is definitely that.

Comment: ...moreover, testing *in practice*, `curl -v http://example.com/ | md5sum -` and `curl http://example.com/ | md5sum -` emit identical checksums, so the diagnostic information **definitely** is going only to stderr and thus bypassing the pipeline.