# Getting exit code 141 when reading from stdin with a Python script with "set -o pipefail" set

Tags: python, pipe

This is a minimal possible example of the problem I have encountered:

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import fileinput

# I
line = sys.stdin.readline()
while line:
    exit(0)
    line = sys.stdin.readline()

# II
for line in fileinput.input():
    exit(0)
    pass

# III
stdin_input_iter = enumerate(sys.stdin)
try:
    next(stdin_input_iter)
    exit(0)
except StopIteration:
    exit(0)
```

Shell script:

```
set -o pipefail
yes | ./test.py ; echo $?
```

The result of running this shell script:

```
141
```

All of the versions: `I`, `II`, and `III` in the Python script result in exit code `141` while I would like them to simply exit with `0`.

Intuitively I understand that my Python script wants to `exit(0)` while `yes` is still writing to the Python's stdin and due to the behavior enforced by `set -o pipefail`, this results in the `141` exit code.

The only solution to overcome this problem I have found so far is to simply continue reading the stdin until the input is exhausted but I am wondering if there is any other solution for my Python script to prevent the exit code `141` from happening.

Comment: For an explanation of why this happens, see the closely related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/41516177/14122. Don't have a laptop with me (for probably about two hours) so I can't immediately write up a focused version for this variant, but hopefully it's obvious after reading the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ yes || :; } | ./test.py
```

or

```
./test.py < <(yes)
```

...will ignore any exit status from `yes` reflecting its inability to write to stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean that I can do nothing on the Python script's side to prevent this from happening?