# ansible-lint risky-shell-pipe asks for pipefail option but it doesn't work

Tags: shell, ansible

The [ansible-lint](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/risky-shell-pipe/) documentation suggests code like:

```
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        set -o pipefail # <-- adding this will prevent surprises
        false | cat
```

Unfortunately this gives me an error: `/bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail` and it appears that the `pipefail` option [is not available](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/illegal-option-o-pipefail) in `dash` (the default `/bin/sh` in Ubuntu 22.04). Any advice?

Comment: `set -o pipefail` is a `bash` feature. Ansible runs `sh` by default (as reported by the binary used in the error message). If you want to use this you need to change the shell with the [`executable` option of the module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-executable).

Comment: Mind, I don't think it's accurate to say that `set -o pipefail` prevents surprises -- [it also can _create_ surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516177/bash-zcat-head-causes-pipefail). I'd argue that people expecting shell error-handling to be intuitive or simple are operating on unexamined assumptions; those assumptions lead to [things like the wildly unintuitive behavior of `set -e`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), and are better replaced with explicit, hand-written and hand-reviewed error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The `pipefail` command needs to run in `bash`.

As you know (per comments), the documentation changed after you posted the question. The documentation, https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/risky-shell-pipe/, now suggests this:

```
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: |
      set -o pipefail # <-- adding this will prevent surprises
      false | cat
    executable: /bin/bash
```

The difference between the two, of course, is the use of the keys `cmd:` and `executable:`. The latter ensures that your command is run in a bash shell where pipefail will work.

Comment: Actually, the documentation [changed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/commit/14941dffa81bba2b978a2c0873c2da835fda0ca2) after I quoted it.

Comment: @JamesFoster that's just annoying of them! I'm glad they got it right eventually, and I suppose you got your answer sooner or later, but OMG!